# Getting "object not set to an instance of an object" error while Publish project after updating Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, publish

Visual Studio throws error "object not set to an instance of an object" while Publish application with Folder Publish. Issue started after updating latest version of Visual Studio 2019

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

**Resolution:** Once 'Publish' is clicked *FolderProfile.pubxml* & *FolderProfile.pubxml.user* files will be created under PublishProfiles folder inside project folder. Move these files out from PublishProfiles folder to the Project folder. Close Visual Studio, load project solution again and publish. Now publish profile will be loaded by default. [Folder publish profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqztL.jpg)